# AngularJs - Calling controller function from directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In an angularjs project I am using a directive to upload files by drag/dropping them in a dropzone. In the directive I need to call a function that is defined within my controller.

Here is what I am doing:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('myController', myController)
    .directive('fileDropzone', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                file: '=',
                fileName: '=',
                test: '&callbackFn',
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                var  processDragOverOrEnter;
                processDragOverOrEnter = function (event) {
                    if (event != null) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                    event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'copy';
                    return false;
                };
                element.bind('dragover', processDragOverOrEnter);
                element.bind('dragenter', processDragOverOrEnter);
                return element.bind('drop', function (event) {
                    var file, reader;
                    if (event != null) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                    reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function (evt) {
                        console.log(reader.result);

                        scope.test({});
                    };
                    file = event.dataTransfer.files[0];
                    reader.readAsText(file);
                    return false;
                });
            }
        };
    });

    function myController()
    {
         var vm = this;

         vm.test = function () {
           console.log("It works !");
         };
    }
})();
```

html file:

```
<div class="container">
    <md-content file-dropzone layout="column" layout-align="center center" class="md-list-item-text" md-whiteframe="1" style="padding:1em;margin:0.5em 0.5em;" flex>
        File drop zone
    </md-content>
</div>
```

While the console.log(reader.result) instruction does display the file content in the console, the message "It works !" is not shown, which means the function test() is never called.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Add HTML file info also..

Comment: as you have created isolated scope then where you are using directive inside of any controller there you will get instance of it use `ctrl ` as fourth parameter of link function

Comment: then you can call function of controller

Comment: Can we register myController as directive controller?

Comment: check this: http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/ycBFL/

Comment: I have included the html file.

Comment: @selvassn, this is the example I am working from.

Comment: you have missed to add  callback-fn="vm.test()" in directive element at html file

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```js
var app = angular.module('exApp', []);

app.controller("Ctrl", function ($scope) {
  $scope.test = function () {
   console.log("Hi you called ctrl function");
  };
  $scope.param = function(name){
  console.log("My name is " + name);
  }
  $scope.testing = function(role){
  console.log("I'm a "+ role);
  }
});

app.directive("testDir", function () {
  return {
    scope: {
      test: "&callFuc",
      param:"&withparam",
      testing:"&"
    },
    template: `<button ng-click="test()">Call Test!
               </button>
               <button ng-click="param({name:'Mani'})">With param!
               </button>
               <button ng-click="clickHere()">Click Me!
               </button>`,
    link:function(scope){
        scope.clickHere = function(){
            scope.testing({msg:"Javascript Developer"});
        };
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="exApp">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div test-dir call-fuc="test()" withparam="param(name)" testing="testing(msg)"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This example is without parameter;

```
   scope: {
                file: '=',
                fileName: '=',
                test: '&',
            }
```

```
<a ng-click="test()">Call test</a> // in directive

<md-content file-dropzone layout="column" test="vm.test()"
            layout-align="center center" class="md-list-item-text"
            md-whiteframe="1" style="padding:1em;margin:0.5em 0.5em;" 
            flex>
   File drop zone
</md-content>
```

Comment: After further testing this is the only solution that worked for me, thanks.

Comment: This answer needs more love

Answer (score -1):

You can access the directive controller by specifying the fourth variable in link function.

Updated Link function:-

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
  console.log(ctrl.test());
}
```

Comment: Please add comment before downvoting an answer. It will be helpful in future answers

Comment: I have not downvoted the answer, but it does not work for me. I have the following error: "Cannot read property 'test' of undefined". If I try to display ctrl in the console it indeed shows "undefined".

Comment: @Hal, I was asking to those person who were downvoting this answer.
Can you register myController as directive controller?

Comment: By adding following key-value to directive object, we can create directive controller.
return {
    controller: 'myController',
    controllerAs: 'ctrl',
    bindToController: true
 }; myController will only be accessible to this directive only. Refer https://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2015/01/02/exploring-angular-1.3-bindToController.html

Comment: I have just tried that and it worked, thank you. Actually I just added this to the directive definition: "controller: myController", plus what you mention in your answer (replacing ctrl by myController).

Comment: For some reason, adding the definition "controller" in the directive had impact on the rest of the solution and angular could not inject services into controllers anymore... I used Manikandan's solution and it worked.

Answer (score -2):

You need to pass **ctrl** as fourth parameter inside **link** function.