# Use Controller function / variable in Directive ,not work

Tags: angularjs

forgive My poor English!I try my best to say clearly my problem.
I would to use function of contoller in the directive.I know the problem have been discussed for many times. I take this question for reference. [here !](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44239423/angularjs-calling-controller-function-from-directive).But My question is a little different from theirs. the image is as follows:
[image: the image is here],In the html,I have a slippery border in the right,which created by directive.If click the button in slippery border ,it will trigger the function.It doesn't work,so I create three buttons in the html just like in the slippery border(the code is as follows),then the buttons work! So I think the scope range caused the problem! But I don't know how to solve it, can anyone help me? thx

any Descriptive vagueness，Please let me know ,thx!

following is My code:

1.app.js code

```
var MakeApp = angular
  .module('newApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch',
    'ui.bootstrap'
  ])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: '/dashboard/dashboard.html',
            controller: 'dashboardCtrl',
            cache: false,
        })
        .when('/ui-property', {
            templateUrl: 'property/property_list.html',
            controller: 'propertylistCtrl',
            cache: false,
        })



  MakeApp.directive('generalFilter', ['$compile','$location','builderService', function($compile, $location,builderService) {
        return {
            restrict: 'C',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.$location = $location;
                var template = "";
                scope.$watch('$location.path()', function(locationPath) {
                    element.removeClass("hidden");
                    switch (locationPath) {
                        case '/ui-brand':
                            template = '<a class="builder-toggle"><i class="icon-wrench"></i></a>' + 
                                       '<div class="inner">' +
                                       '<div class="builder-container"><brandlistfilter>1 this is for sam test</brandlistfilter></div></div>';
                            break;

                        case '/ui-property':
                            template = 
                                       '<a class="builder-toggle"><i class="icon-wrench"></i></a>' + 
                                       '<div class="inner">' +
                                       '<div test-dir call-fuc="test()" withparam="param(name)" testing="testing(msg)"></div>'
                            break;
                        default:
                            element.addClass('hidden');
                    }
                    element[0].innerHTML = template;
                    $compile(element.contents())(scope);

                });
            },
        };
    }]);
```

2.propertylistCtrl.js code:

```
'use strict';
var result
var propertylistmodule = angular.module('newApp');

propertylistmodule.controller("propertylistCtrl", function ($scope) {
  $scope.test = function () {
   alert("Hi you called ctrl function");
  };
    $scope.param = function(name){
  alert("My name is " + name);
  }
  $scope.testing = function(role){
  alert("I'm a "+ role);
  }
});
propertylistmodule.directive("testDir", function () {
  return {
    scope: {
      test: "&callFuc",
      param:"&withparam",
      testing:"&"
    },
    template: 
    '</br></br></br></br></br>'+`<button ng-click="test()">Call Test!
               </button>
               <button ng-click="param({name:'Mani'})">With param!
               </button>
               <button ng-click="clickHere()">Click Me!
               </button>`,
    link:function(scope){
        scope.clickHere = function(){
            scope.testing({msg:"Javascript Developer"});
        };
    }
  };
});
```

property_list.html code:

```
 <div>
  <div test-dir call-fuc="test()" withparam="param(name)" testing="testing(msg)"></div>
</div>
```

I appreciate in advance

Comment: Where do you use the directive?

Comment: Show us your `property_list.html`. Where did you attach your testDir directive?

Comment: @krutkowski86 I have attach the code,thx

Comment: @Syedur directive is in the 'propertylistCtrl.js' the slippery border was created in the 'app.js' .I think it is the cause why it does not work ,but I don;t know how to solve it,do you have some tips? thanks ～

Comment: Please put together a minimal viable test here: https://next.plnkr.co/ you can sign in with github or just work anonymously and just save/update the plnkr page and it will update the URL then share it here to demonstrate the problem with some running code.  Hard to determine what's wrong just with bits and pieces so try to recreate the problem with the minimal extra stuff from your project (can leave out routing etc. just show the ctrl and two directives or whatever is necessary to recreate the problem).